# Фіртка чи хвіртка?

Tags: значення-слів, різниця-між-словами, діалектизми

Не раз чув як люди із мого міста ворота називають "фірткою" і я також досить часто вживаю це слово. Одного разу я вирішив його загуглити і яким же було моє здивування, коли я майже нічого не знайшов. Не знайшов я цього слова і в СУМі, однак там є слово "[хвіртка](http://sum.in.ua/s/khvirtka)".

Але ж не може такого бути, щоб стільки людей помилялись і вживали неіснуюче слово. Можливо "фіртка" - це якийсь діалектизм (можливо галицизм), який просто не потрапив до СУМу?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Перш за все зверну увагу, що тут мова йде не про різні слова, а про різну вимову одного слова.
Подивімось на походження цього слова (ЕСУМ)

[image]

Тобто, спочатку був звук [f]. То звідки ж взялось хв? Справа в тому, що від початку в українській мові не було звука [f], він був чужим для мовців. Тому при запозиченні чужих слів його заміняли на інші звуки. Приклади (давно засвоєних імен): Пилип (Филипъ), Хома (Фома), Матвій (Матфѣй).

Від 15-го століття українці стали заступати [f] на звукосполуку [xw] (пол. forta > укр. хвіртка), спрощувану до [x] перед приголосними та губними голосними звуками (пол. futro > укр. хутро, пол. fura > укр. хура). {Детальніше - див. "Історичну фонологію У.М." Шевельова, розділ 48.9}

У передмові до Грінченкового "Словаря української мови" (1909 р.) зазначено: "Въ виду того, что звукъ ф у большинства украинскаго народа выговаривается как хв (передъ гласной, кромѣ у) или х (передъ согласной и передъ у), мы, составляя словарь на букву ф, помѣстили въ него лишь тѣ слова, для которыхъ въ нашихъ матеріалахъ не нашлось дубликата съ хв или х..."

Звук [f] був звичним, в першу чергу, для тих прошарків населення (в першу чергу - інтелігенції), хто контактував із польською та російською мовами (в яких цей звук був природнім). Тому його заміна на звуки [xw] вважалась за ознаку неосвіченості, й у літературній мові не прижилась (за винятком кількох слів - хвиля, хвіртка). В той же час, для мовців, які сприймають звук [f] за звичний, спостерігається тенденція зворотньої заміни [xw] на [f] (навіть там, де [f] раніше не було) - Хвастів > Фастів, хвороба > фороба, хвіст > фіст.

Див. також [тут](https://uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA:%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%B7_%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8E_%D0%A4#cite_note-2)